# Any idea on how to recreate this blurry effect on text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I'm working on a school event and I don't have lots of experience in Photoshop. So I would like some tips on how to recreate this text. Your help is very appreciated

[image: ![Date Text]

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around [tour] and get a sense of who and what we are as a community. Please also take a look at [ask] and [answer] questions to learn about how to pose your queries and what to expect from replies. Also a good idea to look over [help/behavior] to learn about our community's behavioural expectations. As currently written, this doesn't give us a sense of what you've tried, where you are getting stuck, and so is very broad - so much so that it might well start gathering votes to close based on how broad it is... I'd review those areas and edit it! Welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Outer glow, stroke, and drop shadow....

[image]

The stroke lowers the opacity at the edge of the characters, creating a slight "blur" impression.

[image]

[image]

Note the **contour** of the Drop Shadow....

[image]

These are merely **basics**. Fiddle with it until you are happy.

There may have been a slight motion blur applied after all this as well.

You can convert the text layer with the Layer Styles to a Smart Object, then apply a monition blur as a smart filter:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google "Outer Glow" and "Drop Shadow".

Comment: Although I have to agree the question lacks research, I don't think "Google this" is a good enough answer. Perhaps better to just add that as a comment instead.